# How to overwrite the data in a file with bash

Tags: bash, encryption, erase

I'm writing a bash script that encrypts the data of a folder or file

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name=$1
tmp_file=/tmp/tmpfile.tar

# tar compress file
tar -cf $tmp_file $file_name;

# encrypt file
gpg -c $tmp_file

# remove temp file
rm -rf $tmp_file $file_name

# mv encrypted file to orignal place
mv ${tmp_file}.gpg $file_name
```

but the data will still be recoverable by using **photorec** or similar methods...

Is there a way to ensure the absolute deletion of the original file in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try [srm](http://sourceforge.net/projects/srm) or [wipe](http://wipe.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

I gather it is impossible to just pipe the file into gpg, as you would already have tried that?

Comment: sure, that would be the better sollution, but the i am more concerned with destroying the original file.

Comment: But at least that would avoid the temporary file. One file to wipe is better than wiping two.

Comment: yea yea :) thats why i gave you +1, but I wana know about wiping that one file...

Answer (score 1):

This should also work:

```
rm -Pf file
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a ramdisk to create the temp file in?  Alternatively if the data is that sensitive maybe you should be using an encrypted file system?